# Preventing TabControl selection in Silverlight

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol

Is there any way to prevent the change of a tab in TabControl in Silverlight 4?

A simple case is when I've got a form with some data, and I want to ask the user if he/she wants to save this data before actually changing the tab.

I've seen code examples on how to do this in WPF, but not in Silverlight.

What can I do to stop the tab from changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind SelectedIndex to a property on your data context.

```
<sdk:TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <sdk:TabItem Header="TabItem">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <sdk:TabItem Header="TabItem">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    </sdk:TabItem>
</sdk:TabControl>
```

In the SET accessor, write your code to check whether the user really wants to do what they're trying to do.

```
public class Context : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _SelectedIndex = 0;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Really?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                _SelectedIndex = value;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Net effect is, if the user chooses 'cancel' on the dialogue the private variable is never changed - the PropertyChanged event fires, rebinding the selected index to the existing value.

Hope this is what you were trying to accomplish.

UPDATE (11/10/2012) - Alternate method (possibly for SL5?). Write code behind to tie into SelectionChanged event of your TabControl, reset the tab control's selected item property based on your test.

```
    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Really?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (result != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                ((TabControl)sender).SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(TabControl_SelectionChanged);
                ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
                ((TabControl)sender).SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(TabControl_SelectionChanged);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but didn't work. The OnPropertyChanged appears to be ignored by the TabControl if the same value is set. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly changed between Silverlight 4 and 5, this used to work. Check my updated solution above.